# SQL update row where id = 1

Tags: php, sql, insert

I'm having problems with my php script.

Im settings these variables:

```
$v1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["v1"]);
$v2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["v2"]);
$v3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["v3"]);
$v4 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["v4"]);
```

I want these values to be updated to the row of my db where id = 1 every time (the row already exists and just need to be updated).

should I then insert or update the row?
I've tried this without success:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (v1, v2, v3, v4) WHERE id = 1";
$sql .= "VALUES ('$v1', '$v2', '$v3', '$v4')";
```

Comment: You need to be doing an UPDATE instead of an INSERT, if the row is already in the database.

Comment: The correct syntax should look more like: UPDATE table1 SET v1 = '$v1', v2 = ... WHERE id = 1

Comment: i give it a shot! thanks for reply

Comment: The word "update" appears 4 times in your question, including the title.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use an `UPDATE` rather than an `INSERT`.
Try this:

```
UPDATE table1 set v1 = '$v1', v2 = '$v2', v3 = '$v3', v4 = '$v4' WHERE id = 1
```